# react native IOS The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

when Uploading build to App Store

Issues facing  The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Answer (score -1):

Just check your Info.plist
please provide the missing Strings
and clean the build

Working perfect .......